# How can create collapse tableviewcell & every row contain plus button in every row in tableview?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have tableview every row contain plus button must when press on button add below row can remove this row by button and more detail in below screenshot [this image contain ui must to do in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nITqw.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you share what you have written till now? This way we can help you modeling this

Comment: Please review [ask].

Comment: I have ui like in screenshot in my question so i want make this ui , what the mechanism  to make that

Comment: @Devmobile - start by using google (or whatever) to search for `ios uitableview expand collapse section` ... you'll find many, many, **many** results with examples, discussions, tutorials, etc.